# retrieve and display image on Android from MySQL using servlets

Tags: android, mysql, image, servlets

You may find this question common and going around for quite a long time. The scenario is, I'm trying to develop Android app which works on dynamic data stored in MySQL database. On one of the android form user selects roll number and class of the student. When Show Details button is clicked, I want to call a Servlet which will take these two variables and fire SQL query on DB to retrieve image of the student. 
I need this image to be displayed on my android screen.
It will be great help if anyone can help in with the image sending from Servlet and displaying on android part.

App --> Servlet --> DB (retrieve image) -->Servlet --App(Display Image)

Please provide sample code, it will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following resources searching on google. I have reviewed the code (not running) an I think that you have the necessary pieces for solve your problem

1. How to get a BLOB from database (Server Side): http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1325
2. How to display a image in a Servlet (Server Side): http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetImage.html
3. How to load images from a remote server (Android Client): http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Loading_images_from_a_remote_server

Google is a powerful tool ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions Ernesto, it helped me resolve the issue. :) thanks again.